# From one df per year to one multi-indexed df in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck with the following situation: I've got statistical data covering multiple years, each year being retrieved from a different file read into a dataframe.

So basically I have multiple dataframes, one per year, each looking like the follinwing:

```
    cat geo1        geo2        geo3
0   A   0.709238    0.669532    -0.465389
1   B   -1.426102   -0.152918   0.700080
2   C   -0.486294   -1.619334   -1.711047
3   D   0.392837    -0.754785   -1.686076
4   E   0.603256    0.997562    -0.534222
```

With 'cat' being a product category and geo1 through geo3 being geographic regions

What I would like to end up with is the following:

```
                   year1    year2    year(n)
cat     region
A       geo1
        geo2
        geo3
B       geo1
        geo2
        geo3
```

However, I can't seem to get that done.

Any hint how to go about this is very much appreciated!
Best, Joe

Comment: reading in each file in a loop, adding a column called year for each file, append all the data together, then do a pivot table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load multiple years in one table (possibly concatenate tables for each year, with an identifier variable `yearX`):

```
In []: df
Out[]:
  cat      geo1      geo2      geo3   year
0   A  0.709238  0.669532 -0.465389  year1
1   B -1.426102 -0.152918  0.700080  year1
2   C -0.486294 -1.619334 -1.711047  year1
3   D  0.392837 -0.754785 -1.686076  year1
4   E  0.603256  0.997562 -0.534222  year1
5   A  0.709238  0.669532 -0.465389  year2
6   B -1.426102 -0.152918  0.700080  year2
7   C -0.486294 -1.619334 -1.711047  year2
8   D  0.392837 -0.754785 -1.686076  year2
9   E  0.603256  0.997562 -0.534222  year2
```

Use `melt()` to tidy your data:

```
In []: df = df.melt(value_vars=[c for c in df.columns if 'geo' in c],
                    var_name='region',
                    id_vars=['cat', 'year'])

In []: df
Out[]:
   cat   year region     value
0    A  year1   geo1  0.709238
1    B  year1   geo1 -1.426102
2    C  year1   geo1 -0.486294
3    D  year1   geo1  0.392837
4    E  year1   geo1  0.603256
5    A  year2   geo1  0.709238
6    B  year2   geo1 -1.426102
7    C  year2   geo1 -0.486294
8    D  year2   geo1  0.392837
9    E  year2   geo1  0.603256
10   A  year1   geo2  0.669532
11   B  year1   geo2 -0.152918
12   C  year1   geo2 -1.619334
13   D  year1   geo2 -0.754785
14   E  year1   geo2  0.997562
15   A  year2   geo2  0.669532
16   B  year2   geo2 -0.152918
17   C  year2   geo2 -1.619334
18   D  year2   geo2 -0.754785
19   E  year2   geo2  0.997562
20   A  year1   geo3 -0.465389
21   B  year1   geo3  0.700080
22   C  year1   geo3 -1.711047
23   D  year1   geo3 -1.686076
24   E  year1   geo3 -0.534222
25   A  year2   geo3 -0.465389
26   B  year2   geo3  0.700080
27   C  year2   geo3 -1.711047
28   D  year2   geo3 -1.686076
29   E  year2   geo3 -0.534222
```

Then pivot:

```
In []: df.pivot_table(columns='year', index=['cat', 'region'])
Out[]:
               value
year           year1     year2
cat region
A   geo1    0.709238  0.709238
    geo2    0.669532  0.669532
    geo3   -0.465389 -0.465389
B   geo1   -1.426102 -1.426102
    geo2   -0.152918 -0.152918
    geo3    0.700080  0.700080
C   geo1   -0.486294 -0.486294
    geo2   -1.619334 -1.619334
    geo3   -1.711047 -1.711047
D   geo1    0.392837  0.392837
    geo2   -0.754785 -0.754785
    geo3   -1.686076 -1.686076
E   geo1    0.603256  0.603256
    geo2    0.997562  0.997562
    geo3   -0.534222 -0.534222
```

Comment: Bloody hell...this looks neat - just when I muddled my way through creating pivots and flattening them again...I'll try this.
In any case: you guys are awesome!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot` from pandas once you get all the dataframes. You can find example [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html). Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mate - I've successfully tried this - although the procedure is quite convoluted in the end, will try FabienP's suggestion next, as that seems to be a lot neater. Defintely appreciate your help though!